# Problem: Decide positive whole number $e$ such that $13^e \equiv 32 (\mod 37)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem:

Decide positive whole number $e$ such that $13^e \equiv 32 \pmod{ 37}$

I know how to solve the equation $x^k \equiv b \pmod{m}$ where $k, b, m$ are given.

However how do I find the power satisfying the congruence equation above ?

Thanks

Comment: You can always try $e=1,2,3,\dots,35$. If you hit one that works, you win.

Comment: Hint: $e \leq 10$

Comment: Is that the only way of solving this ? What if the numbers where enormously, should I then sit and try every power ?

Comment: Why ? Fermats little theorem states $a^{36} \equiv a (\mod 37)$ but $13 \neq 32$ ?

Comment: There is no universal (efficient) way of finding $e$ ? Every method so far is brute-forcing the number ?

Comment: Thanks, miracle173 please tell me why Fermats little theorem helps me here ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I can't mark it as a solution because your answer is a comment.

Comment: I guess index calculus might be applicable, but this is such a small case. Yeah, discrete logarithm problems are hard in general.

Comment: There is a big gap between "not efficient" and "brute force".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) says that
$$a^{36} \equiv 1\; \pmod{37}$$
 so  if 
$$13^e=32\;\pmod{37}$$ 
then 
$$13^{36k+r}\equiv 32 \;\pmod{37}$$ 
for an $e \in \{0,\ldots,36\}$. So it is sufficient to check the numbers in $\{1,\ldots,36\}$

All the powers $\{1,13^1,13^2, ..., 13^{35}\}\;\pmod{37}$ are different and $13$ is called a [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)  $\pmod{37}$.
$r$ is called the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) of $32$ to the *base* $13$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{37}$.

Finding the discrete logarithm in finite groups or fields is a computational difficult problem a fact that is used by some  *public key cryptography* systems.

If you want to solve your calculation by hand a simple way is to calculate the logarithms of base $2$. This involves only 37 mutiplication by $2$ and some subtractions of $37$. Complete the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
e &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&\ldots\\
\hline
2^e \pmod{37}&1&2&4&8&16&32&27&17&\ldots\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Renaming the caption gives:

$$
\begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
\log_2 n &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
\hline
n&1&2&4&8&16&32&27&17&34&31&25&13&26&15&30&23&9&18\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
\log_2 n&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31&32&33&34&35\\
\hline
n&36&35&33&29&21&5&10&20&3&6&12&24&11&22&7&14&28&19\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The discrete logarithm behaves similiar to the known logarithm function. We have

$$ \log_{13}(32)=\log_2(32)/\log_2(13)=5/11=5*23=7 \pmod{36}$$
because the inverse of $11 \pmod{36}=23$. This can be found using the Euklidian Algorithm.

if $\phi(p)$ can be factored in coprime parts then the calculation can be accelerated. There exist interesting probabilistic and deterministic for the discrete logarithm. Details can be found in this [Chapter of the book of Andrew Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/discrete.logs.hff.pdf)

Comment: For discrete logarithm(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html), the base $(13)$ has to be a primitive root (of  $37$), right? For that you need to prove/supply reference that $13$ is a primitive root of $\pmod{37}$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee, yes must be a primitive root

Answer (score 2):

I don't like 13: it's too big. I'll use the base 2 (and hope to get lucky that it's primitive):

The powers of 2 are:

$$2, 4, 8, 16, -5, -10, 17, -3, -6, -12, 13, \ldots$$

Both $13$ and $32$ appear on this list ($32 = -5$). Thus,

$$ 2^5 = 32 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2^{11} = 13 \qquad \pmod{37} $$

Therefore,

$$ 13^{5/11} = 32 \pmod{37} $$

so all that's left is to compute

$$ 5 \cdot 11^{-1} \pmod{36} $$

Fortunately, $11$ and $36$ are relatively prime. Were this not true, there would be some more technicalities to deal with, related to the fact the base is not a primitive element.

Comment: +1 You have finished your answer before I finished my addendum to my answer. But it is had the same idea. So it pleases me.

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic approach:

$$13=-24=-3\cdot8\pmod{37}\;,\;\;\text{so}$$

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;3\cdot25=75=1\pmod{37}\\
\bullet&\;\;\;8\cdot14=112=1\pmod{37}\end{align*}$$

Thus, we get that (doing arithmetic modulo $\;37\;$ all the time)

$$24^{-1}=3^{-1}8^{-1}=25\cdot14=-12\cdot14=4\cdot(-3\cdot14)=4\cdot(-5)=-20=17$$

and thus

$$13^{-1}=(-24)^{-1}=-17=20\pmod {37}$$

Comment: I think you are on the wrong track: the question is about logarithm and not about the multiplicative inverse

Comment: No, it's not @miracle173 : it's about a modular equation which definitely needs no (discrete) logarithm at all to be solved. Perhaps you missed the "elementary number theory" tag...

Comment: and where did you compute the solution of $13^e=32 \pmod{ 37}$ ?

Comment: You are right: somehow I read $\;13^{-1}=32\pmod{37}\;$ , yet going to discrete logarithms is way too much imo, particularly for elementary No. Theory. Perhaps something like $$13^2=21\pmod{37}\;,\;\;13\cdot 3=2\;,\;\;13\cdot 7=17$$ and etc. Of course, continuing like the above is a way of doing disc. logarithms.